# Pushing updates to specific users

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I've seen this technique used by Facebook, they have a join list feature which would allow certain users to receive the update version while other people would still be using the old version.

How is this possible to accomplish?

Comment: you probably want more details about what you mean by "update version" . if you mean how people get different versions of a page. Take a look at sessions. if you mean dynamic update, then take a look at ajax calls, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing the inline approach, Facebook rolls out changes gradually across their server farm. Tech journalists and early adopters are provisioned onto the set of servers that receive the new updates first.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve this:

- Mark old and new users with a Database Boolean flag.
- Check this condition and show different versions to old and new users.